# When to return a JSON and/or a status code in Node to handle success/result on the client?

Tags: node.js, xmlhttprequest

In my Node-Express backend I have a route which execute certain operations and **returns a status message to let the client know the response.**

e.g.

**server side**

```
.post('/api/route', function(req, res) {
     if (condition) { res.json({result: "ok"}); return; }
     else res.json({err: "errorX"});
}
```

then on the **client side**

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
            var responseJson = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            if (responseJson.result && result="ok") { // do something }
            else if (responseJson.error && error="err1") { // do something }
            else if (responseJson.error && error="err2") { // do something }
        }
    };
```

I know that in Node I can also return a statusCode

e.g.

```
res.status(500).send(null);
```

and then catch client side by

```
xhr.status
```

**What is the right approach (error/result field VS status code) to handle operation's outcome in Node?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my sort-of informed opinion, that every 'good' code, that is, one that isn't an error (such as 100-300) should just return the status code. If something is broken, it should return the status code + the error, so that debugging can go easier.

But again, this is just my opinion. Please take it with a grain of salt.

Comment: thanks for your answer. However, how would you return a different error based on the backend logic (e.g. if a specific check fails)?

Comment: `if(something == true){ return something } else { return something else }`

Comment: so not just the status code but also a string / object?

Comment: The status code and a string. Like invalid something or another.